# Sending data from textinputs to next php script

Tags: php, mysql, session

Here is my php script http://jsfiddle.net/3BGD4/ panel looks like there with button Zapisz from this link  http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/HKyWY/.
I make echo$ for inputs and it shows nothing. There are two options, sending is bad, or texinputs are wrong. Any advice ? If you don't know how to solve it, vote for it.
oh, and here is my validation script:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<?php
ob_start();
session_start();


$host="mysql.cba.pl"; // Host name
$username="MSobal"; // Mysql username
$password="sobalm"; // Mysql password
$db_name="msinzynierka_cba_pl"; // Database name
$tbl_name="User"; // Table name

// Connect to server and select databse.
//mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect");
$link=mysqli_connect("$host", "$username", "$password");

//mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");
mysqli_select_db ($link ,  $db_name );

if (isset( $_SESSION['myusername']) && isset( $_SESSION['mypassword']) ){

$myusername = $_SESSION['myusername'];
$mypassword = $_SESSION['mypassword'];


$sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE username='$myusername' and password='$mypassword'";
$result=mysqli_query($link,$sql);

}




// Define $myusername and $mypassword
$myusername=$_POST['myusername'];
$mypassword=$_POST['mypassword'];

// To protect MySQL injection (more detail about MySQL injection)
$myusername = stripslashes($myusername);
$mypassword = stripslashes($mypassword);
$myusername = mysql_real_escape_string($myusername);
$mypassword = mysql_real_escape_string($mypassword);

//$sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE username='$myusername'                 and                       
 password='$mypassword'";
//$result=mysql_query($sql);

// Mysql_num_row is counting table row
$count=mysql_num_rows($result);

//If result matched $myusername and $mypassword, table row must be 1 row

if($count==1){

// Register $myusername, $mypassword and redirect to file "login_success.php"

$_SESSION['myusername']=$myusername;
$_SESSION['mypassword']=$mypassword;

header("location:login_success.php");
}
else {
echo "Niepoprawny login lub hasło";
echo $myusername;
echo $mypassword;
}

ob_end_flush();
?>

<form action="" method="post">
Username: 
<input type="text" name="myusername">
<br>
Password: 
<input type="password" name="mypassword">
<br>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
<br><br>
<a href="sessions_test_2.php">check</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Here it is login_success.php

```
<?php
session_start();
if ( isset( $_SESSION['myusername'] ) ){

header("location:main_login.php");
}
?>

<html>
<head>
<link href="menugora.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-2" />

</head>
<body>

<ul id="menu">
<li><a href="login_success.php?value=1">Kategorie</a></li>
<li><a href="login_success.php?value=2">Towary</a></li>
<li><a href="login_success.php?value=3">Klienci</a></li>
<li><a href="login_success.php?value=4">Towar-Zamówienie</a></li>
<li><a href="login_success.php?value=5">Zamówienie</a></li>
<li><a href="login_success.php?value=6">Wyloguj</a></li>
</ul>

<?php

$arg = (int)$_GET['value'];

switch ($arg)
{
case 1:
include('kategoria.php');
break;

case 2:
include('towar.php');
break;

case 3:
include('klient.php');
break;

case 4:
include('towarzamowienie.php');
break;

case 5:
include('zamowienie.php');
break;

case 6:
include('logout.php');
break;


}
?>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Suggestion, [**Don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: Sidenote: Missing `session_start();` required when using sessions. `$_SESSION['myusername']` - otherwise, no go.

Comment: what's the HTML of the page?

Comment: @LozCherone and that is the reason why it isn't working ?

Comment: @cyadvert open first link there is html css

Comment: Plus these `$_SESSION['myusername']="myusername"; $_SESSION['mypassword']="mypassword";` should most probably be 
`$_SESSION['myusername']=$myusername; $_SESSION['mypassword']=$mypassword;` blind (*educated*) guess. ;-)

Comment: in your `checklogin.php` put somewhere on top `var_dump($_POST); die();` and see if the data you posting is there. If it is - then sending is good. If nothing in $_POST - sending is bad...

Comment: @Fred-ii- Still I can't log inside. I made everything you said

Comment: @cyadvert I've got array(0) { }

Comment: this means there is nothing being sent.

Comment: What's inside `login_success.php`?

Comment: By the way, place `ob_start(); session_start();` - `ob_start();` first.

Comment: @Fred-ii- look at login_succeess.php

Comment: I posted something for you to test with. This worked for me, and you just need to fill in the DB codes and a few other things. @user3299430

Comment: And read the "Footnotes" in my answer, including what Vikas posted. Your form inputs are invalid. @user3299430

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### EDIT - rewrite (start)

***Disclaimer***: **I strongly suggest you not store passwords in plain text** like that, nor to use `mysql_*` functions. Use [`mysqli_*`](http://php.net/mysqli) with [prepared statements](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) or [PDO](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php).

Here, I wrote it for you. Complete with login form, success page and logout page.

**(Page 1, Page 2, Page 3)**

**Important** - All your included files should contain the following at the top:

```
session_start();
if (isset($_SESSION['myusername']) && isset($_SESSION['mypassword'])){
// content
}

else{ echo "What you want to show here.";
}
```

otherwise, anyone will be able to access those pages.

**Sidenote**: You cannot mix `mysqli_*` with `mysql_*` functions, they are not compatible with each other.

And replace `("host","username", "password", "database")` with your own information below.

**Page 1**

PHP/HTML form

```
<?php
ob_start();
session_start();

$link = new mysqli("xxx","username", "password", "database");
$tbl_name = "User";

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
$myusername = mysqli_real_escape_string($link,$_POST['myusername']);
$mypassword = mysqli_real_escape_string($link,$_POST['mypassword']);

$_SESSION['myusername'] = $myusername;
$_SESSION['mypassword'] = $mypassword;

$sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE username='$myusername' and password='$mypassword'";
$result=mysqli_query($link,$sql);

$count=mysqli_num_rows($result);

if($count==1){
header("location:login_success.php");
}

else{
echo "Sorry, you are not logged in.";
}

} // isset submit

ob_end_flush();
?>

<form action="" method="post">
Username: 
<input type="text" name="myusername">
<br>
Password: 
<input type="password" name="mypassword">
<br>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

**Page 2** (if logged in) - login_success.php

```
<?php
session_start();
if (isset($_SESSION['myusername']) && isset($_SESSION['mypassword'])){

echo "If you see this message, then you have successfully logged in.";
echo "<br>";
echo "Your account name is: ";
echo $_SESSION['myusername'];
echo "<br>";
echo "Your account password is: ";
echo $_SESSION['mypassword'];

echo "<hr>";
echo "<a href='logout.php'>Logout</a>";
}

else{
echo "Sorry, you are not logged in.";
}
```

**Page 3** (Logout Page) - logout.php

```
<?php
session_start();
session_destroy();
echo "<a href='login.php'>Log back in</a>";
```

### END of Edit

---

---

---

### Original answer

Here's a quick method to check if the username and password SESSION names get carried over when submitting and passed on to another page.

**Sidenotes**: Use `var_dump($_SESSION['myusername']);` and `var_dump($_SESSION['mypassword']);` to debug/troubleshoot. `$_SESSION` could be replaced with `$_POST`

e.g. `var_dump($_POST['myusername']);` to see if anything gets set or not, later on.

***Disclaimer***: **I also strongly suggest you not store passwords in plain text** like that, nor to use `mysql_*` functions. Use [`mysqli_*`](http://php.net/mysqli) with [prepared statements](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) or [PDO](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php).

You will need to fill in the rest in order to suit your DB codes.

In `page 1` code, you will notice a link:

```
<a href="sessions_test_2.php">check</a>
```

That will show the username and password SESSION names in there.

The form's action is set to `action=""`

**Page 1:**

```
<?php
ob_start();
session_start();

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
// Define $myusername and $mypassword
$myusername=$_POST['myusername'];
$mypassword=$_POST['mypassword'];

// Register $myusername, $mypassword and redirect to file "login_success.php"

$_SESSION['myusername']=$myusername;
$_SESSION['mypassword']=$mypassword;

echo $_SESSION['myusername'];
echo "<br>";
echo $_SESSION['mypassword'];

// header("location:login_success.php");

} // isset submit

ob_end_flush();
?>

<form action="" method="post">
Username: 
<input type="text" name="myusername">
<br>
Password: 
<input type="password" name="mypassword">
<br>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
<br><br>
<a href="sessions_test_2.php">check</a>
```

**Page 2** (sessions_test_2.php)

```
<?php
session_start();
if (isset($_SESSION['myusername']) && isset($_SESSION['mypassword'])){

echo $_SESSION['myusername'];
echo "<br>";
echo $_SESSION['mypassword'];
}
```

---

**Footnotes:**

`session_start();` must be used inside ALL pages using sessions.

***Plus these*** in both your jsfiddle files: (as Vikas stated in an answer)

```
<input type="myusername" placeholder="Login" autofocus />
<input type="mypassword" placeholder="Has&#322;o" />
```

should be:

```
<input type="text" name="myusername" placeholder="Login" autofocus />
<input type="password" name="mypassword" placeholder="Has&#322;o" />
```

---

You could use this method:

```
$_SESSION['myusername'] = $_POST['myusername'];
$_SESSION['mypassword'] = $_POST['mypassword'];
```

---

### DB

Your DB code would look something like this:

```
session_start();

...

if (isset( $_SESSION['myusername']) && isset( $_SESSION['mypassword']) ){

$myusername = $_SESSION['myusername'];
$mypassword = $_SESSION['mypassword'];


...

$sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE username='$myusername' and password='$mypassword'";

...

}
```

Comment: after var_dump($_SESSION['myusername']); and var_dump($_SESSION['mypassword']); string(6) "that_what_i_write_and_is_a_login" string(6) "that_what_i_write_and_is_a_password" Niepoprawny login lub hasło

Comment: after var_dump($_POST['myusername']) and var_dump($_POST['mypassword']); i've got NULL NULL Niepoprawny login lub hasło

Comment: Ok, which is good, it showed you the right information. Now incorporate your DB code and you should be all set. Just follow the same convention that I have. @user3299430

Comment: It's the "session" names part that's important, since you will be using that for all your other pages. @user3299430

Comment: I edited my answer. Look near the bottom under **"DB"** - @user3299430

Comment: you have to wait, ok ? Give me some time

Comment: I can't find mysql_num_rows() in mysqli.

Comment: `mysql_num_rows` and `mysqli` don't mix. @user3299430 Notice the `i`? Are you using `mysqli_` or `mysql`?

Comment: look for my edition. Is that correct ? I'm making it first time so, be patient.

Comment: If this stuff is correct (i deleted dots) afret one try for login, i get Niepoprawny login lub hasło Username input and Password, both empty and button submit which makes nothing(refreshing website after on clicked). And check redirect url, after on clicking on it nothing has been shown. Only name of the page for "sessions_test_2.php"

Comment: No, it's incorrect. Your login success `login_success.php` should have `if (isset( $_SESSION['myusername']) && isset( $_SESSION['mypassword']) ){

$myusername = $_SESSION['myusername'];
$mypassword = $_SESSION['mypassword'];` and not in the first page. As I said, my page 1 is your first page, and page 2 is your `login_success.php` @user3299430 - What you did was the complete reverse of my examples.

Comment: You are mixing `mysqli_` with `mysql_` functions. You have `mysqli_*` for DB connections, while using `mysql_real_escape_string` you can't use that. This `$myusername = mysql_real_escape_string($myusername);` should be `$myusername = mysqli_real_escape_string($link,$myusername);` and the same for the other one. @user3299430

Comment: I rewrote it entirely for you. Reload the page and see **EDIT - rewrite (start)** down to where it says **END of Edit**. @user3299430 and again, this is not a safe method to use, but that's what you originally wanted to use.

Comment: And I added a "Logout" feature. @user3299430 - All tested. So it can't go wrong, really.

Comment: works but tottally destroy my layout. It looks like normal html formula.

Comment: I'll tell you what; pay my hourly fee of $95.00 <=(**time I already spent**) plus another 1/2 hour tacked on top of that, and I'll do the **job** just like you want it. The time I invested in this is worth that in the real world of economics. This is the last %*&$ time I help anyone out like this; bravo, history has been made today. Destroyed your layout, key-riced, **fill in the blanks man**. @user3299430

Comment: Sorry, I'm 15 years old and I want to make my first php site. I don't want you to make it for me. I'm from norway. I wasn't playing around. I was sleeping.(Diffrent time). I told you what is going on from my side.I've also changed this css and it looks as it should. Thanks a lot for all help. Don't be angry on me, I'm at the beginning in php. One more time. Thanks a lot!

Comment: You're welcome. I like to help people, but I expect a certain amount of collaboration on the other person's part. I can't be expected to do everything. My initial answer consisted of the basic building blocks to get you up & running with the proper method. When I noticed you had set it up in reverse, I wrote the script by hand in its entirety, tested it on my server with the same table name & columns and once everything worked, I posted the answer afterwards. I couldn't setup CSS / JS etc., it's just too time-consuming. I'm not angry, just overwhelmed. I wish you well. @user3299430 - Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Try to change your html as:

```
<div class="container">
<form id="signup" action="checklogin.php" method="post">
        <div class="header">
                <h3>Logowanie</h3>
        </div>

        <div class="sep"></div>

        <div class="inputs">
                <input type="text" name="myusername" placeholder="Login" autofocus />
                <input type="password" name="mypassword" placeholder="Has&#322;o" />
                <input type="submit" id="Submit" value="Zaloguj">
        </div>
</form>
</div>

</body>

</html>
```

Change login_success.php to :

```
<?php
session_start();
if ( !isset( $_SESSION['myusername'] ) ){

header("location:logout.php");
}
?>

<html>
<head>
<link href="menugora.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-2" />

</head>
<body>

<ul id="menu">
<li><a href="login_success.php?value=1">Kategorie</a></li>
<li><a href="login_success.php?value=2">Towary</a></li>
<li><a href="login_success.php?value=3">Klienci</a></li>
<li><a href="login_success.php?value=4">Towar-Zamówienie</a></li>
<li><a href="login_success.php?value=5">Zamówienie</a></li>
<li><a href="login_success.php?value=6">Wyloguj</a></li>
</ul>

<?php

$arg = (int)$_GET['value'];

switch ($arg)
{
case 1:
include('kategoria.php');
break;

case 2:
include('towar.php');
break;

case 3:
include('klient.php');
break;

case 4:
include('towarzamowienie.php');
break;

case 5:
include('zamowienie.php');
break;

case 6:
include('logout.php');
break;


}
?>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: redirecting to non exsiting page main_login.php and destroy my login and password inputs